# Extracting basic statistics (raster data) from different latitudes using R?

Tags: raster, r, spatial-statistics, zonal-statistics

I want to extract the mean, min and max stats from latitude -50 to 0 and from 0 to 50 etc. No idea how to do this.

I would prefer using R for this as I have a lot of these to do.

[image: Raster Map on R]

Answer (score 1):

One solution (using R) is to create extent objects of the bounding boxes you're interested in, and then `crop()` to that extent and use the `cellStats()` function to extract the mean, min, max, sd, etc. for that region. Here's what that looks like in code:

```
library(raster)

myraster = raster("PATH/TO/RASTER.tif")

extmat1 = matrix(data = c(-180,180,-50,0), nrow = 2, ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE)
extent1 = extent(extmat1)

extmat2 = matrix(data = c(-180,180,0,50), nrow = 2, ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE)
extent2 = extent(extmat2)

r1 = crop(myraster, extent1)
r2 = crop(myraster, extent2)

max1 = cellStats(r1, stat = 'max')
min2 = cellStats(r2, stat = 'min')
```

... and so on, for whatever stats you're interested in.

Comment: Jepson thank you this worked perfectly! Really appreciate it.